# Google Apps Script - declaring a blank array as an object property doesn't add it to the object's keys

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

**Question Details**

I'm having an issue declaring an empty array in an object to use later in my google apps script.  As far as I can tell, this is a problem within the inherited parts of Javascript, but if I am incorrect then please correct me.

Here is the code where I declare my arrays in an object:

```
var cities = {  
    'Austin': Array(),
    'Bemidji': Array(),
    'Harmony': Array(),
    'Red Wing': Array(),
    'Rochester': Array(),
    'Spring Valley': Array(),
    'Winona': Array()
};
```

I have a method in my script that adds objects to each of these arrays, and then another method that works with the objects added or behaves completely differently if no objects were added to a particular array at all.

Due to this script being a couple versions old, I have an old line that creates the arrays as it finds them, which is the only reason this script has limped along for months before I found a problem (No objects exist for Austin, so the array is never created.)  Here is that block:

```
if (typeof cities[cityName] == "undefined") 
{
    cities[cityName] = Array();
    Logger.log(cityName + " was not found in the cities object, adding now.");
}
```

Clearly, I can create arrays to use later, and it's paying attention to the object declaration because no errors are thrown when referencing it.  Why am I having problems declaring empty arrays in an object to begin with?

**Testing Done**

I threw a line in to track what the keys were in the cities object, but all I ever got in the Google Apps Script logger was "[17-02-10 11:28:08:494 CST] [Rochester, Bemidji, Harmony, Red Wing, Spring Valley, Winona]".  Timestamp is first, the second set in brackets is what the keys in that array always ends up being.

I tried declaring my arrays with brackets, and I also declared the arrays outside of the object declaration but neither worked, both inside of and outside of my main method.  Example of what I mean:

```
var cities = {
    "Austin": [],
};
cities["Austin"] = Array();
```

**Research Done**

I spent a fair amount of time on Google attempting to find what I was doing wrong.  I ran across a couple stack overflow questions that suggested declaring the arrays inside the object using this or var, but that seemed to be a waste of time when I tried it.

**Original Code**

```
/*
 * Name: COM wordpress jobs publisher
 * Author: Matthew Speltz
 * Purpose:
 *      This was built to automatically move jobs onto the Wordpress site from a google sheets document.  It will automate an otherwise 
 *  very technical task for people who are unable or uninterested in learning what is needed to build the website correctly.  No 
 *  warranty or guarantee of service is offered with this script, it is built to accomplish one task and do it sorta-OK.
 * 
 * Date Created: Unknown.
 * Date Last Modified: 2/10/2017
 * 
 * Notes 4/20/2016:
 *      Worked on getting the interface with Wordpress and XML-RPC.  This is now creating posts correctly on the website, but the page 
 *   HTML is still not working.  This is still relatively tiny so I'd rather not completely rewrite this, but I suppose I can rewrite 
 *   the City posting method without fracturing anything too badly.  Setting this down, I need to think about other things for a while.
 *
 * Notes 5/2/2016:
 *      I updated the script to include Bemidji in the list of cities to get updated.
 *
 * Notes 11/29/2016:
 *      I noticed that Austin and Red Wing were not posting to the website correctly.  Troubleshooting it now, should update when fixed.
 *
 * Notes 2/10/2017:
 *      It was reported to me that Austin was not posting to the website correctly again, previous note was left unfinished.  I found the 
 *  root cause to be that there were no postings listed for the open hours sheet, because when I added a fake listing it worked fine.  
 *
 *      In the course of troubleshooting, I found that a couple of the big predefined HTML variables had extra junk in them that shouldn't
 *  have been there, so I removed that.
 *
 *
 *  Variables:
 *      styleHTML
 *          This string is the HTML code needed on pages to make the buttons display correctly.
 *      jobDescriptionHTML
 *          This string is the HTML code of the job description.
 *      otherRequestButtonHTML
 *          This string is the HTML code for the button that will offer a generic method to contact someone.
 *      applyOnlineButtonHTML
 *          This string is the HTML code for the Apply Online button.
 *      ui
 *          This is defined to be shorthand for the user interface module in Google Sheets Scripts
 *      wordpressCredentials
 *          This object contains the URL of the XML-RPC server, the username from the person running the script, and the password of 
 *          said user.  Owned variables are 'url', 'username', and 'password' respectively.
 *  
 *  Objects:
 *      cities
 *          This object contains city names, which in turn are objects holding the job postings.  Job posting objects have 2 properties, 
 *          'postinghtml' which contains the HTML for the posting, and 'hours' which contains the number of hours the job has.  Once 
 *          the pageHTML is written, this is also added to this object for the method updatePostingPage to use.
 *      jobPostingPages
 *          This object contains the finished HTML for all of the job posting pages.  This is entered in by writePage, and is used when 
 *          pushing pages to Wordpress with updatePostingPage.
 *          
 *  Methods:
 *      mainUpdateWebpage()
 *          this is the entry point for the script to function correctly.  It should call the other methods in order, and contains what I 
 *          would consider the main thread.  It starts by iterating through the line items in the Open Hours google sheet, moving the items 
 *          to a temporary variable 'jobPosting' with more human-readable names, then sending 'jobPosting' off to writePosting to do it's 
 *          thing.  Then it calls writePage to finish formatting and sending the data, then informs the user that the transfer of 
 *          information is finished.
 *      writePage(city, cityName)
 *          This contains the logic for writing up the entire posting page once the job postings are written.  It handles sorting job 
 *          postings by the number of open hours, then writing out the page data with the job description and needed buttons code.  
 *          Finally, it pushes the prepared page over to updatePostingPage to finish sending the data to Wordpress.
 *      getDepartment(departmentNumber)
 *          A simple method, it takes a house number and translates it into a house name, returning the string of the house name.
 *      writeJob(jobPosting)
 *          This takes the nicer formatted line item from the Open Hours google sheet and translates it into a 2-week schedule and summary 
 *          of the hours of the position.  It finishes by adding the posting to the cities object under the appropriate city.
 *      updatePostingPage(HTML, city)
 *          This takes the page HTML given to it, then overwrites the old HTML on Wordpress under the city given.  It needs to authenticate 
 *          with Wordpress, confirm the connection is open, then signal to delete the old data and save the new data.  It will manually step
 *          through the list of cities, as defined by the variable jobPostingPages.  It accesses the statically written HTML string and pushes that 
 *          to the city page.
 */


var styleHTML = "<style type=\"text/css\">\n\t.su-button {\n\t\tdisplay: inline-block !important;\n\t\ttext-align: center;\n\t\t";
styleHTML += "text-decoration: none !important;\n\t\tbox-sizing: content-box !important;-moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;\n\t\t";
styleHTML += "-webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;\n\t\ttransition: all .2s;\n\t\t-o-transition: all .2s;\n\t\t";
styleHTML += "-ie-transition: all .2s;-moz-transition: all .2s;\n\t\t-webkit-transition: all .2s;\n\t}\n\t.su-button-style-soft span { ";
styleHTML += "background: 0 -20px url('../images/styles/style-soft.png') repeat-x }\n\t.su-button-style-soft:hover span { background: 0 0 ";
styleHTML += "url('../images/styles/style-soft.png') repeat-x }\n\t</style>";

var jobDescriptionHTML = "<h2>Full Job Description</h2>\n\tEnsures that the daily needs of each client are met through teaching, counseling,";
jobDescriptionHTML += " advising, and providing a positive role model in a manner which enables the greatest degree of independence possible";
jobDescriptionHTML += " in their activities of daily living. Duties include: Assisting with and encourage independence in activities of";
jobDescriptionHTML += " daily living including personal hygiene, development of personal responsibility, basic health care, appropriate";
jobDescriptionHTML += " social skills, etc. Transportation to activities, housekeeping, and medication administration.\n\t<div>\n\t<h2>";
jobDescriptionHTML += "Qualifications:</h2>\n\tWe are looking for people who are:\n\t<ul>\n\t\t<li>Honest,</li>\n\t\t<li>Enjoy having fun,";
jobDescriptionHTML += "</li>\n\t\t<li>Can work well with a team,</li>\n\t\t<li>Can treat people the way that they want to be treated,</li>";
jobDescriptionHTML += "\n\t\t<li>Have the right attitude,</li>\n\t\t<li>And want to do their best at work.</li>\n\t";
jobDescriptionHTML += "</ul>\n\t</div>\n\t<div>\n\t<h2>Requirements:</h2>\n\t<ul>\n\t\t<li>Must be 18 years of age or older,</li>\n\t\t<li>";
jobDescriptionHTML += "Must have a valid Driver's License and acceptable driving record.</li>\n\t</ul>\n\t</div>";

var otherRequestButtonHTML = "<a class=\"su-button su-button-style-flat\" style=\"color: #ffffff; background-color: #2d89ef; border-color: ";
otherRequestButtonHTML += "#246ebf; border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;\"";
otherRequestButtonHTML += " href=\"http://cardinalofminnesota.com/?p=4975\" target=\"_blank\"><span style=\"color: #ffffff; padding: 0px 16px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 26px; border-color: #6cacf4; border-radius: 5px; ";
otherRequestButtonHTML += "-moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; text-shadow: none; -moz-text-shadow: none; -webkit-text-shadow: none;\">Didn't find what you were looking for? Tell us!</span></a>";

var applyOnlineButtonHTML = "<a class=\"su-button su-button-style-soft\" style=\"color: #ffffff; background-color: #d90a1a; border-color: #ae0815; border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 7px; -webkit-border-radius: 7px;\"";
applyOnlineButtonHTML += "href=\"http://cardinalofminnesota.formstack.com/forms/application\" target=\"_blank\"><span style=\"color: #ffffff; padding: 0px 20px; font-size: 16px; line-height: 32px; border-color: #e4545f; border-radius: 7px; ";
applyOnlineButtonHTML += "-moz-border-radius: 7px; -webkit-border-radius: 7px; text-shadow: none; -moz-text-shadow: none; -webkit-text-shadow: none;\">Apply Online Now</span></a>";


// Cities object contains city names, which each contain an array with job posting objects.  
// Job posting objects have 2 properties, postinghtml which contains the HTML for the posting, and hours which is the number of hours the job has.
var cities = {
    "Austin": Array();
    "Bemidji": Array();
    "Harmony": Array();
    "Red Wing": Array();
    'Rochester': Array();
    "Spring Valley": Array();
    "Winona": Array();
};

// Wordpress login object.
var wordpressCredentials = 
{ 
  url: /* URL... */,
  username: "/* User... */",
  password: "/* Password... */"
};

//this contains the finished HTML for the job posting pages.
var jobPostingPages = {
  'Austin': "",
  'Bemidji': "",
  'Harmony': "",
  'Red Wing': "",
  'Rochester': "",
  'Spring Valley': "",
  'Winona': ""
};

// Main function.  Iterates through job postings.
function mainUpdateWebsite()
{

  //Marking the log as beginning.
  Logger.log("Beginning the transcription of the job postings to the website.");

  // Iterate through the Sheet, turning lines into job postings.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // # Sort the unnamed array into an JS object with named variables.
  // This starts after the header rows, i is line, 2 really starts on line 3.
  for (var i = 2; i < data.length; i++) 
  {
    //skipping this loop if there is nothing on this line.
    if (data[i][0] == "") continue;

    var jobPosting = {};
    jobPosting.county = data[i][0];
    jobPosting.city = data[i][1];
    jobPosting.departmentID = data[i][2];
    jobPosting.departmentName = getDepartment(data[i][2]);
    jobPosting.ID = data[i][3];
    jobPosting.description = data[i][4];
    jobPosting.dateAvailable = data[i][5];
    jobPosting.sunday1 = data[i][6];
    jobPosting.monday1 = data[i][7];
    jobPosting.tuesday1 = data[i][8];
    jobPosting.wednesday1 = data[i][9];
    jobPosting.thursday1 = data[i][10];
    jobPosting.friday1 = data[i][11];
    jobPosting.saturday1 = data[i][12];
    jobPosting.sunday2 = data[i][13];
    jobPosting.monday2 = data[i][14];
    jobPosting.tuesday2 = data[i][15];
    jobPosting.wednesday2 = data[i][16];
    jobPosting.thursday2 = data[i][17];
    jobPosting.friday2 = data[i][18];
    jobPosting.saturday2 = data[i][19];
    jobPosting.week1Hours = data[i][20];
    jobPosting.week2Hours = data[i][21];
    jobPosting.totalHours = data[i][22];

    // writeJob is expected to push the job posting to the cities object
    writeJob(jobPosting);
  }

  //Appending to Log.
  Logger.log("Done parsing job postings from the Spreadsheet.");

  // iterate through cities in the cities object, pushing the results to the jobPostingPages object.
  for (var key in cities)
  {
    Logger.log("Checking this key now: " + key);

    // If this is a valid city, i.e. not a property inherited from 'object'...
    if (cities.hasOwnProperty(key))
    {
        // call writePage() on this city.
        writePage(cities[key], key);
    }    
  }

  updatePostingPage()
}


// ## Write webpage with job postings.
// This takes the job posting strings in each city array in the cities structure.  It combines them with HTML that is page-specific, then pushes the whole HTML string to the JobPostingPages structure.
// the variable city is the array for this city name from the cities structure.  
// the variable cityName is just the name of the array.
function writePage(city, cityName)
{
  // Adding to log.
  Logger.log("Writing posting page for %s.", cityName);


  // beginning text on the page.  pageHTML is the HTML code that will be sent to the Wordpress page.
  var pageHTML = styleHTML + "<h1>Direct Support Professional (DSP)<//h1>\n";
  pageHTML += "<h4>" + cityName + ", MN<//h4>\n&nbsp;\n";
  pageHTML += jobDescriptionHTML + "\n" + applyOnlineButtonHTML + "\n\n<h2>Available Hours:</h2>\n\n\n";

  //Used later, noPostings is a boolean that is set to false when a posting is found.
  var noPostings = true;

  //iterate through postings to sort highest into pageHTML first.  Remove postings from object as they are used.
  while (true)
  {
    //used for eliminating running getOwnProperties() more times than needed, and jumping out of the loop when appropriate.
    var length = city.length;
    if (length == 0) break;

    // mostHours is the posting found with the most hours, index is the index of that posting.
    var mostHours = 0;
    var index = -1;

    //iterate through the array, comparing hours to the mostHours variable, updating index as appropriate.
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
      if (city[i].hours > mostHours)
      {
        mostHours = city[i].hours;
        index = i;
        noPostings = false;
      }
    }

    //Skipping invalid postings once the other postings are gone.
    if (index == -1) 
    {
      Logger.log("No further job postings are available to push to the cities.  Moving to next step.");
      break; 
    }

    //append biggest element to the pageHTML.
    pageHTML += city[index].postingHTML;
    Logger.log("Appending posting ID %s", city[index].ID);

    //remove biggest element, and run it again.
    city.splice(index, 1); 
  }

  //if there was no posting, noPostings was not updated, and this will update the job list to show no postings.
  if (noPostings)
  {
    pageHTML += " <b> There are no available positions in " + cityName + ", MN at this time. </b> \n\n\n";
  }

  //adding the final text to pageHTML.
  pageHTML += applyOnlineButtonHTML + "\n\n" + otherRequestButtonHTML + "\n";

  jobPostingPages[cityName] = pageHTML;
}


// ## Pushing new text to Wordpress.
// this should connect to Wordpress, exchange credentials, then completely erase the old page and write a new one in it's place.
function updatePostingPage()
{
  postIDs = {
    /* names of cities with specific post IDs to the Wordpress Webpage. */
  };

  /* Iterating through the written pages and updating them accordingly. */
  for (var key in jobPostingPages)
  {
    // If this particular key in jobPostingPages was inherited, skip the loop.
    if (!(jobPostingPages.hasOwnProperty(key))) continue;

    //Logging
    Logger.log("Pushing postings for %s to the website now.", key);

    // Call the metaWeblog.newPost API method to edit the existing post
    var query = new XMLRPC.XmlRpcRequest(wordpressCredentials.url, 'wp.editPost');

    // The first parameter is empty since there's no blog ID for WordPress
    query.addParam(""); 

    // Username and password
    query.addParam(wordpressCredentials.username);
    query.addParam(wordpressCredentials.password);

    // use the city to get the correct PostID.
    query.addParam(postIDs[key]);

    /* The blog post content. You can have HTML in the description */
    var cityPosting = {
      post_type: 'page',
      post_status: 'publish',  /* Set to draft or publish */
      post_content: "" + jobPostingPages[key]
    };

    query.addParam(cityPosting);

    var reply = query.send().parseXML();
  }
}

// ## Writing the HTML of the job posting.
// Returns nothing, it handles the logic of making each posting HTML, then pushes the HTML string to the right array in the cities structure.
function writeJob(jobPosting)
{
  // Create posting as a giant string of HTML format.  It will be a table within the page once finished.
  var postingHTML = "<table style=\"text-align: left; padding: 10px; width: 100%; font-size: 12px; border: 0px;\">\n";
  postingHTML += Utilities.formatString("<tbody> <tr> <td> <b> %s </b> | %s | Reference ID: %s </td> </tr>\n", jobPosting.departmentName, jobPosting.description, jobPosting.ID);
  postingHTML += "<tr> <td>\n <table style=\"text-align: center; padding: 10px; width: 100%; font-size: 12px; border: 0px;\">\n";
  postingHTML += "<tbody> <tr> <td></td> <td>Sunday</td> <td>Monday</td> <td>Tuesday</td> <td>Wednesday</td> <td>Thursday</td> <td>Friday</td> <td>Saturday</td> <td>Weekly Total Hours</td> </tr>\n";
  postingHTML += Utilities.formatString("<tr> <td>Week 1</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> </tr>\n", jobPosting.sunday1, jobPosting.monday1, jobPosting.tuesday1, jobPosting.wednesday1, jobPosting.thursday1, jobPosting.friday1, jobPosting.saturday1, jobPosting.week1Hours);
  postingHTML += Utilities.formatString("<tr> <td>Week 2</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> </tr>\n", jobPosting.sunday2, jobPosting.monday2, jobPosting.tuesday2, jobPosting.wednesday2, jobPosting.thursday2, jobPosting.friday2, jobPosting.saturday2, jobPosting.week2Hours);
  postingHTML += "</tbody> </table> </td> </tr> </tbody> </table>\n <br></br>\n\n\n";


  //This if statement adds the city of this posting to the Cities structure if it doesn't exist.
  if (typeof cities[jobPosting.city] == "undefined") 
  {
    cities[jobPosting.city] = Array();
    Logger.log(jobPosting.city + " was not found in the cities object, adding now.");
  }

  // Adding posting to the Cities struct.
  cities[jobPosting.city].push({postingHTML: postingHTML, hours: jobPosting.totalHours, ID: jobPosting.ID});

  //logging for later debugging, as needed.
  Logger.log("%s got pushed to the %s array.", jobPosting.ID, jobPosting.city);
}


// ## Speedy return of the department name.
function getDepartment(departmentNumber)
{
  switch (departmentNumber)
  {
    /* Company Specific info. */    
  }

  // if we got to here, the department isn't correct.
  Logger.log("Attempted to lookup department %s", departmentNumber);
  return 'NO DEPARTMENT';
}
```

Comment: This sounds like either an timing mistake (the code that initializes the properties runs chronologically before the code that expects it) or that you're somehow loading an old version of the server-side code (which is a feature that Apps Scripts supports, I think, so make sure you're not doing that). Based on the information you're given, though, I can't be sure about either. The code you have is fine and should do exactly what you expect, so your issue is likely elsewhere (either in project config or in code you haven't shown).

Comment: I think I figured it out.  I still don't have an answer on my original question, but I'm declaring the object in what I think is global scope and defining the arrays within a method, and it's working now.  I posted my anonymized code in my original question for your reference.